# Modern OpenGL , getting a white texture on an object

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, graphics, textures

im trying to load a texture to an object in Modern NVIDIA openGL

i have a square that i want to load the texture to , i use stb_image as my loader

here is the main code :

```
float position1[16]{
    0.0f , 0.0f, 0.0f , 0.0f,
    0.8f , 0.0f, 1.0f , 0.0f,
    0.0f , 0.8f, 0.0f , 1.0f,
    0.8f , 0.8f, 1.0f , 1.0f ,
};

unsigned int Indexs[6]{
    0 , 1 , 2 ,
    2 , 1 , 3

};
VertexBuffer buffer(position1, sizeof(position1));
IndexBuffer Index(Indexs, 6);
Texture Tex("Smile.png");
Tex.Bind();
buffer.Bind();
Index.Bind();
Shader BasicShader("basic.shader");

Renderer renderer; 
glfwSwapInterval(0);


//! MAIN LOOP !!!


BasicShader.Uniform1i("u_Texture ", 0);
BasicShader.Uniform4f("u_Color", 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f );
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window) )

{
    //! RENDER
    renderer.Clear();
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    BasicShader.Uniform1i("u_Texture ", 0);
    BasicShader.Uniform4f("u_Color", 0.f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    Tex.Bind();
    BasicShader.Bind();
    renderer.Draw(buffer, Index, Layout::D4Vertex, BasicShader);



    //! FRAME

    glfwSwapBuffers(window);

    //! EVENTS
    glfwPollEvents();
}

glfwTerminate();
return 0;
};
```

here is my shader its of course being compiled the right way as expected with no errors :

```
#shader vertex
#version 410 core

layout(location = 0 ) in vec4 position;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 texCoord;

out vec2  v_TexCoord;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = position;
    v_TexCoord = texCoord;
};


#shader fragment
#version 410 core

layout(location = 0 ) out vec4 color;

uniform vec4 u_Color;
uniform sampler2D u_Texture;

in vec2 v_TexCoord;

void main()
{
    vec4 texColor = texture2D(u_Texture, v_TexCoord);
    color = texColor;
};
```

here is my draw call :

```
void Renderer::Draw(VertexBuffer& vb,  IndexBuffer& iv, 
                    Layout layout,Shader& shader) 
{
    BufferLayout bufferLayout;
    shader.Bind();
    vb.Bind();
    iv.Bind();
    bufferLayout.SetLayout(layout);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, iv.GetCount(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr);
}
```

this is how i set the buffer layout:

```
void BufferLayout::SetLayout(Layout l)
{
    switch (l) {
        case Layout::NONE :
            glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        case Layout::D2Vertex :
            glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
            glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 
         2,0);
        case Layout::D4Vertex:
            glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
            glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 
        4,0);
    }
}
```

here is my texture class (handels loading parameters and binding ) :

```
#include "Texture.h"
#include "stb_image.h";
#include "Renderer.h"

Texture::Texture(string  path)
    : m_RendererID(0) , m_BPP(0) , m_Height (0) , m_Width (0), 
      m_LocalBuffer(nullptr) , m_FilePath(path)
{
    stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(1);
    m_LocalBuffer = stbi_load(path.c_str(), &m_Width, &m_Height, &m_BPP, 4);
    //seems like the image is there
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glGenTextures(1, & m_RendererID);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_RendererID);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    GLenum temp = glGetError();
    if (temp != GL_NO_ERROR)  throw std::invalid_argument("OPENGL ERROR");
    // I Get  no erros
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, m_Width, m_Height, 0, GL_RGBA, 
                 GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, m_LocalBuffer);
}

Texture::~Texture()
{
    glDeleteTextures(1, &m_RendererID);
}

void Texture::Bind(unsigned int slot)
{
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + slot);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_RendererID); 
}

void Texture::Unbind()
{
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
}
```

and my texture.h file :

```
#pragma once
#include "Renderer.h"

class Texture {
    private :
    unsigned int  m_RendererID;
    string m_FilePath;
    unsigned char * m_LocalBuffer;
    int m_Width, m_Height, m_BPP;

    public:
    Texture(string  path);
    ~Texture();

    void Bind(unsigned int slot = 0);
    void Unbind();

    inline int GetWidth()const { return m_Width; }
    inline int GetHeight()const { return m_Height; }

};
```

basicaly im pretty sure the problem must be somewhere in the code i have posted and all the other code works as expected .

Can anyone spot the problem ?
The result should be a square with the texture "Smile.png" on it and i get a white texture . I do have the file "Smile.png" in my project directory and it seems to me like stb_image can find and load it .

*no erros from `glGetError();`

Comment: I must admit it is difficult to make a _small_ [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) concerning OpenGL. However, you could format your code properly at least...

Comment: I don't see any code that would bind data to the `texCoord` attribute.

Comment: @BDL `case Layout::D4Vertex: glEnableVertexAttribArray(0); glVertexAttribPointer(0,2,GL_FLOAT , GL_FALSE , sizeof(float)*4 , 0);` should do that ... is it correct ? This code is called in the renderer to the BufferLayout class

Comment: That's the setup for attribute 0. You are missing similar code for attribute 1.

Comment: @BDL Thanks! :) can you do a full answer with an example for how it should look ? because I don’t fully understand how to do that ...

Comment: Done, but you should really go over your question and fix the indentations on all code samples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code sample, the setup code for attribut 1 (`texCoord`) is missing. For each attribute used by a shader, a buffer has to be bound, the attribute has to be enabled and the relation between attribute and shader has to be specified.

As said, this is done for attribute 0 but not for attribute 1. The code in the `SetLayout` method could look somehow like this:

```
//Attribute 0: uses first two floats
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 4, 0);

//Attribute 1: uses 3rd and 4th float
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 4, (void*)(2 * sizeof(float)));
```

Comment: Amm it doesn’t work , I’m putting in the buffer the array position1 that you can see at the top of the question. The first two floats are vertex cords , second two floats are texture cords and so on in etch line ... are you sure this is the buffer layout i need to read this array ? I really don’t understand how this works ... but I get a black screen form that layout .

Comment: Yes, I'm 100% sure that this is what you need for your layout. Each vertex has a size of `4 * sizeof(float)`, the uv-coordinates are stored `2 * sizeof(float)` bytes after the positions. There might be more problems in your code, but I honestly refuse to debug it anymore before you fix your formatting problems.

Comment: Also: Since we didn't change anything related to attribute 0, the position shouldn't have changed at all. Are you sure that your color output from the texture is not just black?

Comment: forget what I said I’m sorry forgot to copy a line , You fixed the problem ! Thanks you I was honestly debugging this for two days. The texture is now loading on screen